# Nativescript - list view crash using Android

Tags: nativescript

Using NS 4.1, core 4.1 and android 4.1

I've got a list view with templates and sometimes I have to I navigate back to the list view page and recreate the list.

When doing so on Android - I get the following error

`System.err: Error: There is no entry with key 'org.nativescript.widgets.GridLayout{70646a0 VFE...C.. ......I. 0,449-1440,803}' in the realized views cache for template with key'info'.`

I assume list view is caching views and causes the crash on re-generation of the list view.

Any way to force clear the cache?

Any solutions?

This is happening in Android 8. Not on earlier Androids.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on this:
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1479

For now, you can try replacing your ListView with a [RadListView](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/overview). Or, if you are using a slide transition between the two screens, you can try removing the transition. This has worked for me.